# Set search navigation to inherit from parent site with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, csom, enterprise-search

I am working on a solution in SharePoint Online where I want to accomplish the following using CSOM:

- Set all subsites to inherit search navigation from parent. To achieve this I have  this little code-snippet which actually works and sets a property on a subsite web to inherit parent search navigation.

  ```
          using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("ParentSiteURL"))
          {
          context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(struser, password);
          Web web = context.Site.OpenWeb("SubsiteName");
          var allProperties = web.AllProperties;
          context.Load(allProperties);
          web.AllProperties["SRCH_VERT_SET_WEB"] = "{\"Inherit\":true}";
          web.Update();                
          context.ExecuteQuery();
          }
  ```

However, even though the property is updated and search settings are now set to inherit parent navigation - it's not working.

I need to navigate to "Site settings > Search settings" and click OK for it actually work. So it seems like I am missing an Update of some kind...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have managed termset based navigation on rootsite?

Comment: Nope. I don't have any managed termset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to load it before execute

```
web.AllProperties["SRCH_VERT_SET_WEB"] = "{\"Inherit\":true}";
web.Update();
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.AllProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

as said in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/configure-search-navigation-and-set-to-inherit-from-parent-site-with-csom)

Comment: Already tried. Not Working :(

Answer (score 0):

Using the property `SRCH_VERT_SET_WEB` is probably *not* the right way to do it, since there is no documentation on the subject.

Try a more straight-forward approach like changing [SPWeb.Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation_members) properties.

Check the propertiy values for `UseShared` and the list of navigation nodes in `SearchNav` before and after you modify search inheritance via site settings. You should be able to figure out what changed in the object model and then re-apply it in your code.

Comment: I set UseShared property to true after loading all the navigation nodes. And still it does not work :(

Comment: Finally I was able to achieve it using HttpPost method. Answered it on the originial question as I am unable to do answer it here. Thanks